# Livewire Nested Components Sub-Form

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm having trouble understanding [Nested Components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components). I'm mainly using my nested components to provide a Modal (nested component) in my main components. Ex: a Modal form for some additional info in my Forms on main components.

I hope what I'm trying to accomplish is possible. I have a "partial form" for `Checks` input in many components. Each component has the same exact validation rules and required Model quieres. I want to remove all of those, put them in 1 nested component and then call something like `@livewire('checks.checks-form')` in each main component.

Something like this:

Main Component `TimesheetForm`

View `livewire.timesheets.payment-form` :

some TimesheetForm inputs here

`@livewire('checks.checks-form')`

some TimesheetForm inputs here

Although the data from my nested component (`ChecksForm`) is loaded onto the main component views, the main component views still try to load the validation rules from itself instead of the nested component. I was really hoping to avoid repeting both, my nested component date (which seems to work) AND my nested component validation rules.

Is this something that can be achieved? (I'm sure since anything I have ever struggled with in the TALL stack always comes back with positive results). Thank you for any pointers in the right direction! - Patryk

`App\Http\Livewire\TimesheetPaymentForm`:

```
class TimesheetPaymentForm extends Component
{
    public User $user;

    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user.full_name' => 'nullable',
            'weekly_timesheets.*.checkbox' => 'nullable',
            'employee_weekly_timesheets.*.checkbox' => 'nullable',
            'user_paid_expenses.*.checkbox' => 'nullable',
        ];
    }

    ...

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.timesheets.payment-form');
    }
```

`payment-form.blade.php`:

```
{{-- FORM --}}
   {{-- ROWS --}}    
   <x-forms.row 
        wire: model"user.full_name"
        errorName="user.full_name"
        name="user.full_name" 
        text="Payee"
        type="text"  
        disabled
        >
    </x-forms.row>


     @livewire('checks.checks-form')
```

`App\Http\Livewire\Checks`: Want to use this inside my TimesheetPaymentForm

```
{
    public $check = NULL;
    public $check_input = NULL;

    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'check.date' => 'required',
            'check.paid_by' => 'required_without:check.bank_account_id',
            'check.bank_account_id' => 'required_without:check.paid_by',
            'check.check_type' => 'required_with:check.bank_account_id',
            'check.check_number' => 'required_if:check.check_type,Check',   
            'check.invoice' => 'required_with:check.paid_by',  
        ];
    }
...

    public function render()
    {
        $bank_accounts = BankAccount::where('type', 'Checking')->get();
        $employees = auth()->user()->vendor->users()->where('is_employed', 1)->whereNot('users.id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

        return view('livewire.checks._payment_form', [
            'bank_accounts' => $bank_accounts,
            'employees' => $employees,
        ]);
    }
```

`_payment.form.blade.php`:

```
...
<x-forms.row 
    wire:model="check.paid_by" 
    errorName="check.paid_by" 
    name="paid_by" 
    text="Paid By"
    type="dropdown"
    >

    <option value="" readonly>{{auth()->user()->vendor->business_name}}</option>
    @foreach ($employees as $employee)
        <option value="{{$employee->id}}">{{$employee->first_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</x-forms.row>

<div 
    x-data="{ open: @entangle('check.paid_by') }" 
    x-show="!open" 
    x-transition.duration.150ms
    >

    @include('livewire.checks._include_form')
</div>
<div
    x-data="{ open: @entangle('check.paid_by') }" 
    x-show="open" 
    x-transition.duration.150ms
    >
    <x-forms.row 
        wire:model="check.invoice" 
        name="check.invoice" 
        errorName="check.invoice"
        text="Reference"
        type="text"  
        >
    </x-forms. Row>
</div>
...
```

Comment: It will be possible using [Livewire events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events) but we would need to see actual code (the structure of your components and blade files etc.) in order to provide more accurate guidance.

Comment: Thanks! added component and blade views above.